# Angular js ng-dissabled not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My HTML ...........................................................................

```
 <div id="ButtonController" ng-app="buttons" ng-controller="ButtonController   as controller">

            @*<span ng-disabled="controller.access.canClose">@Html.Kendo().Button().Name("tabDelete").Content("Close").Icon("cancel")</span>
            <span ng-disabled="controller.access.canEdit">@Html.Kendo().Button().Name("Edit").Content("Edit")</span>*@
        <button ng-disabled="controller.access.canClose" class="k-button k-button-icontext" title="Close Tab" type="button" id="tabDelete" >Close</button>
        <button ng-disabled="controller.access.canEdit" class="k-button k-button-icontext" title="Edit" type="button" id="Edit" >Edit</button>
        <button id="save" class="k-button k-button-icontext" >Save</button>

    </div>
```

my js

```
  (function () {
var app = angular.module('buttons', []);

app.controller('ButtonController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myfunctions = function (obj) {
        if (obj != "Stop") {
            $http.get("/home/setButtonRights?tr_code=" + obj)
                   .success(function (response) {
                       buttonVisibility.canClose = response.canClose;
                       buttonVisibility.canEdit = response.canEdit;
                   })
                       .error(function () { alert("Done") });
        } else {
            buttonVisibility.canClose = true;
            buttonVisibility.canEdit = true;


        }
    }

        this.access = buttonVisibility;

});
}
var buttonVisibility = {
    canEdit: true,
    canClose:true
}

})();
```

when i pass "Stop" to this controller buttons still active. I want to disable these buttons when stop obj comes.

Comment: what you meant by `when i pass "Stop" to this controller`

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Invert the expression in ng-disabled or (better) use ng-enabled.

Comment: I don't think that you can have ng-disabled in span.

Answer (score 1):

Why you try to achieve is a bit weird. 
You want to set attribute `disabled` on `<span>` ... but why? `<span>` is not form element. Browser will not respect this attribute on non-form element.

You should either use `<button>` or ng-class like this `ng-class={'disabled':'some-bool-criteria'}`

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra brace in your code. Else it should work fine. Here is the updated one:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('buttons', []);

app.controller('ButtonController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.myfunctions = function (obj) {
        if (obj != "Stop") {
            $http.get("/home/setButtonRights?tr_code=" + obj)
                   .success(function (response) {
                       buttonVisibility.canClose = response.canClose;
                       buttonVisibility.canEdit = response.canEdit;
                   })
                       .error(function () { alert("Done") });
        } else {
            buttonVisibility.canClose = true;
            buttonVisibility.canEdit = true;


        }
    }

        this.access = buttonVisibility;

});

var buttonVisibility = {
    canEdit: true,
    canClose:true
}

})();
```